# How to fix route has error Laravel that showed me when I hovering the Route::has that show me a alert

Tags: laravel, web, laravel-8, laravel-routing

[image: error]

How can I solve the problem shown in the image above (`Route::has`) Laravel?

Comment: That is your IDE, PHP is not throwing an error... do you get a real laravel error? Have you run `composer install`? Switch to a better IDE, in this case `PHPStorm` and install [`barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and then run `php artisan ide:meta` and `php artisan ide:gen`

Comment: That is just a warning in your IDE, whatever it is. You'll need to check your IDE documentation about how to configure it so it understands the Laravel source, or try searching using the IDE name.  If you can't work it out, you could try editing your question and letting us know what your IDE is, and what you've tried to do to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code in another editor if it's showing same error than try to run **composer install** and **composer dump-autoload** then check because sometime some files are missing that we have to fix so try once